# Vertical align checkbox label?

Tags: html, css

I have checkboxes like this:

```
<label class="checkbox-label"><input type="checkbox" value="115">Administrators</label>
```

But I cannot fugure out how to style the label to be center valigned to the checkbox.

I tried adding `vertical-align:middle;`

Thanks

Comment: You'll probably need to use line-height or negative margins for your particular scenario. I'd provide an example, but you've given us no demo or CSS.

Answer (score 62):

This is what I did with your code.

**html**

```
<label class="checkbox-label"><input type="checkbox" value="115">-middle</label>
```

**css**

```
label.checkbox-label input[type=checkbox]{
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    bottom: 1px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/576wT/)

Comment: This is the correct answer since it doesn't alter the html syntax given by the OP.

Comment: Except that it doesn't work.   It brings it closer, but it's still not properly aligned.  Adding vertical-align: text-bottom; to your CSS does though.

Comment: I like this answer better than the duplicated reference answer. Kudos!

Answer (score 6):

Try using:

```
vertical-align: text-bottom;
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kYyD4/)

**Edit:**

```
 <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="115">
 <label class="checkbox-label" for="checkbox">Administrators</label>
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kYyD4/1/)

Comment: @user2043533 check the fiddle. It works for me.

Comment: Yes, that works, but with yours I cannot click the label to check the box.

Comment: You need to add `for="checkboxId"' to the label. See my edit.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Your example does not work if you modify the text size.  I set your fiddle to `font-size: 10px;`, and it failed to align the text with the input.

Answer (score -3):

Adjust the line height of the label.