# Customized check box and label alignment

Tags: css, checkbox

I have created a customized check box where the check box is hidden and a label is customized in a way to appear as checbox . everything is work fine but when I give it a label its not getting aligned properly . here is the fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/130/

```
verticals alignment : middle ;
```

Must have worked but it didnt . can someone help to resolve it

Comment: But where do you want to center it? According to which element?

Comment: I don't want to center it .. Label styled label has to come next to check box

Comment: But there's only a checkbox.

Comment: I referred this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230820/vertical-align-checkbox-label

Comment: Are you sure that you want to center it vertically?

Comment: It should appear like a normal check box with a label

Comment: Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change your HTML code I suggest you to use pseudo-elements to create custom checkboxes.

html

```
<div class="checkboxFour">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxFourInput" name="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
  <label for="checkboxFourInput">styled label</label>
</div>
```

css

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

. checkboxFour {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 20px 90px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.checkboxFour label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #333;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.checkboxFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  background: #26ca28;
}

#boxlabel {
  vertical-alignment: middle;
}
```

Here's the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/132/)

Answer (score 0):

the reason why the label was not displayed was, that you forgot the quotes after your id boxlabel.
If you add the quote the label will be displayed.

For the Styling check this article:
https://blog.kulturbanause.de/2015/03/formular-styling-mit-css-select-listen-radio-buttons-und-checkboxen-individuell-gestalten/

Answer (score 0):

In your code I suggest close a `id="boxlabel"` (there's missing a second `"`) and add `display:inline-block` for .checkboxFour.

Good examples of checkbox stylig you have [here](https://codepen.io/bbodine1/pen/novBm)